# Create a Windows Service Application to update a Sharepoint List.

Tags: sharepoint-online, service-application

I have a requirement to Create a Windows Service Application that can read items from a Web Service and update a Share point Online List. Is it possible to do some work around like this? If yes then please suggest how to proceed in this.